# Identity involving partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am looking for the partial derivative of the function $f$ with respect to $\theta$ in the post https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404578/372675, but had a different answer to the one in the link. The answer in the post is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\left(\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial\ln{f}}{\partial{\theta}}\right) = -\frac{1}{f^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{\theta}^{2}}
\end{align}
$$

Below is my attempt.

$$\mathrm{Let} \; a = \frac{1}{f}, \; b = \frac{\partial\ln{f}}{\partial{\theta}}, \; \mathrm{then}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\left(\frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial\ln{f}}{\partial{\theta}}\right) = a'b + b'a= a'\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\theta}} + b'\frac{1}{f}$$
$$= -\frac{f'}{f^{2}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\theta}} + \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\theta}} =-\frac{1}{f^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\theta}}\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\left(\partial{\theta}\right)^{2}}$$

Why is my answer different from the one above in the last part? Might I have had an incomplete knowledge or an incorrect misunderstanding of the differentiation rules?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=\frac {\partial^{2}f} {\partial\theta^{2}}$.

Comment: it looks like a rule? is there more intuitive way to help me understand why that's the case?

Comment: That is just the **notation** for the second partial derivative w.r.t $\theta$. There is no theorem or rule involved here.

Comment: Your answer is the same as the given answer.  By convention, we write $\partial \theta ^2$ to mean $(\partial \theta)^2$.  Is that your confusion?  In this setting, $\partial \theta^2$ does not mean $\partial (\theta^2)$.

Comment: If we can write $(\partial \theta)^2$ as $\partial \theta^2$, why $\partial^2 f$ to $\partial f$... Or we can?

Comment: What? Its analogous to regular differentiation, take $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx}$ $= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ we write $dx^2$ to mean $(dx)^2$.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \frac{{\partial}^{2}}{\partial{x}^{2}}$$ are **operators and not variable that are being multiplied**. The former being the first partial derivative with respect to $x$, and the latter being the second partial derivative with respect to $x$. Now imagine we have a function $f$ that is dependent on $x$. We define a function $F'$ to be the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, i.e., $$F' = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}f$$ We can now define a new function $F''$ to be the partial derivative of $F'$ with respect to $x$, which is the second partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. We write them as $$F'' = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}F' = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}f\right) = \frac{{\partial}^{2}}{\partial{x}^2}f$$
So to put it in to context, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\right) \neq \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}$$ because, like I mentioned earlier, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}$$is not a variable that you can multiply.

Comment: What does this $-\left(\frac{\partial\ln f}{\partial\theta}\right)^2$ become? $-\frac{\partial^2 \ln^2f}{\partial \theta^2}$? Am I understand correctly? Can't make my head up.. Or it's $-\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial \theta^2}$?

Comment: Neither. If $f$ is a function of $\theta$ and we evaluate $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\ln{f}$ and set it as $u$, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\ln{f} = u$, then $-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\ln{f}\right)^{2} = -(u)^{2}$

Comment: For example, let's say $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\ln{f} = 5\theta$, then $-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\ln{f}\right)^{2} = -(5\theta)^{2} = -25\theta^{2}$

Comment: For a better understanding, I recommend you watch (https://youtu.be/AXqhWeUEtQU) and (https://youtu.be/J08-L2buigM) in order. Hope those help.